# Panda DataFrame on scraped football scores

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, beautifulsoup

New to Python and web scraping. I am trying to import live college football scores via BeautifulSoup (from ESPN) into a Panda DataFrame. I have searched high and low and can't seem to get the imported scores to format correctly.

Once I have it in a Dataframe, I will then import the results into Excel.

Here's what I have so far. The results are in one column all the teams followed by all the scores.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Jims Maximus Hero\Desktop\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.espn.com/college-football/scoreboard/_/group/80/year/2019/seasontype/2/week/11")

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

for tag in soup.find_all("span", {"class":"sb-team-short"}):
    print (tag.text)

for tag in soup.find_all("td", {"class":"total"}):
    print (tag.text)
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Once you have your `page_source`, have you experimented using `pd.read_html()` and extracting your tables in that fashion? It also appears that you can target certain divs using `{'class': 'scoreboard-wrapper'}`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will modify tomorrow and get back to you. I'm learning.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.get('https://www.espn.com/college-football/scoreboard/_/group/80/year/2019/seasontype/2/week/11')

df  = pd.read_html(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="401119297"]/div/div/section/div/table').get_attribute('outerHTML'))
results = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//article[contains(@class, 'scoreboard football')]")
df = pd.DataFrame()
for result in results:
    score  = pd.read_html(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="'+str(result.get_attribute('id'))+'"]/div/div/section/div/table').get_attribute('outerHTML'))
    score = score[0].dropna(axis=0, thresh=4)
    df = pd.concat([df,score])
print(df)
```

Yielded:
[image]